# Structure sheaf as intersection over stalks at closed points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3317456/33855) it is stated (under the condition that $X$ is integral) that $\mathcal O_X (U) = \bigcap_{x \in U} \mathcal O_{X,x}$.

Since we're taking an intersection over all points in $U$, it seems that it might be enough to take the intersection over all *closed* points, since (locally) closed points correspond to maximal ideals, in which case the stalk is smaller. Is this true?

I don't understand why we need that $X$ is integral for the above equality to hold, so I am worried I am overlooking something.

Comment: There exist schemes without closed points. See https://www.math.utah.edu/~schwede/Papers/SchemeWithoutPoints.pdf So without some constraints, the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: If $X$ is an integral and *Jacobson* scheme, then $U_0=U\cap X_0$ (where by zero subscript we mean subset of closed points) and $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\bigcap_{x\in U_0}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result you are asking about is true. You can look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630752/an-integral-domain-a-is-exactly-the-intersection-of-the-localisations-of-a-a). As for the importance of $X$ being integral, you need to ask yourself what $\bigcap_{x\in U} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ means. One of the very convenient aspects of integral schemes is the presence of a function field, $K(X)=\mathcal{O}_{X,\xi}$, where $\xi$ is the generic point of $X$. In particular, there are injections $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\to K(X)$. We identify $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ with its image in $K(X)$ and this is exactly the sense in which $\bigcap_{x\in U}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is even defined.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like the projective limit can sometimes be used to replace the intersection. Can this help here?

Comment: @Earthliŋ Projective limit ... of what diagram? There is no obvious diagram here.

Comment: @ZhenLin If $S$ is a finite set of closed points in $X$, one can define $\mathcal O_{X, S} = \varinjlim_{U\supset S}\mathcal O_X(U)$, generalizing the definition of a stalk in a single point. Then for any inclusion $S\subset T$ of finite sets of closed points in $X$, the direct limit yields a map $\mathcal O_{X,S} \leftarrow \mathcal O_{X,T}$, so one could ask whether $\mathcal O_X(U)=\varprojlim_{S \subset U}\mathcal O_{X,S}$ where the limit taken is over all finite subsets of $U$. But I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around it and like you seem to imply, this might not make sense.